# Issue while reading string value from db and print in html page

Tags: java, html

I have an issue while reading the data(String) from database and print in html page.

Example: I stored string value "hello <--extra spaces here-->    world" in db and i tried to get and print in html page it displays like "hello world" i hope it is an issue in html side can any one suggest regarding this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you complaining that "hello world" displays like "hello world"? What is your issue?

Comment: My issue is like it doesn't show multiple white spaces in between hello & world

Comment: @maaartinus - His first example has extra spaces between the two words, but SO automatically strips them down to one. I've edited to highlight the problem.

Comment: Actually i am giving 3 spaces between hello world but it shows single space.I want exact word what i am stored in db.

Comment: There much more chars which may make problems, especially <, >, &. In case you want them display as they are, you'd need some simple escaping.

Answer (score 4):

just apply

`white-space: pre;` attribute and print the value

for example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
p
{
white-space:pre;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>
hello       world
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is indeed an apt thing to do, but the problem in this particular question is that, it would be better if the value in the database is self contained and not depend on any other outside tag. Suppose, if you omit the `<p>`, then you wouldn't get the desired behaviour. However, I don't think he is having this as a real life scenario.

Comment: @Adeel I didn't get your point by ` it would be better if the value in the database is self contained and not depend on any other outside tag.` , as far as I understood this issue ,OP is storing values in DB that include space, which is getting retrieved correctly but the issue is HTML without css ignores ultiple white space.

Comment: @org.life.java: Your solution might be the preferred one. I prefer this, by the way. But as I stated, that the value would print differently in different HTML containers. It would work if `white-space` set appropriately, and wouldn't otherwise. You can't just print it anywhere in the HTML code. You will need a container with specific CSS attribute set. I hope you are seeing my point now.

Comment: @Adeel No :), can you give me an example where it would fail.

Comment: @org.: Okay, tell me would this value would be printed as expected outside `<p>` in your example? No, right. But if the value itself is surrounded by `<pre></pre>` then no matter where you place it, it would work as expected. Now, you see my point?

Comment: @Adeel ow... agree. but that OP will have to manage and , again if OP will insert `<pre>hello    world</pre>` in DB then in some other place he will have to manage it. if its just for view purpose then the thing you are telling is doable.[I wouldn't do it]. +1btw

Comment: @Jigar: I wouldn't do that too, but it depends on the case. In real life we usually build a proper way with all bells and whistles.

Comment: @Adeel Agree . . .! :) . btw Thanks for this discussion

Answer (score 1):

Of course, HTML wouldn't take extra spaces into account.

```
<pre>Hello          World</pre>
```

Or

```
Hello<pre>          </pre>World
```

Or

```
Hello&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;World
```

will work.

You might like to save the value as the first option, in the database. In this way, you don't need to worry about any external attribute, I mean whether `white-space` is set or not. The latter two would work, but not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

When displaying output to the browser, extraneous whitespace is stripped. You'll have to convert each space to &nbsp; in order to have it show in the browser. Alternatively, you can wrap the content in <pre> tags to preserve the spacing.